# submitting a form and then redirecting with hidden variables to paypal?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, paypal

I need to submit a form for classified ads on our website when a user clicks the submit button. The price of an ad is based on how many words along with how many weeks it will run so the PayPal button I have reads the hidden "amount" field I have set up. How can I have my form submit and then redirect to PayPal with the hidden amount variable still holding its value? Any other methods would also be welcome.

Edit:
Ok, I've made my own php script to email the information to me from my original form, I had been using a cgi script my webhost hosted.

Now I email myself just fine and I'm trying to find out how to send my hidden variables to paypal from there when I redirect to it. Heres what I'm trying right now.

```
<?php 
 $to = "info.whatzup@gmail.com" ; 
 $from = $_REQUEST['email'] ; 
 $name = $_REQUEST['Name'] ; 
 $headers = "From: $from"; 
 $subject = "Classified Tests"; 

 $fields = array(); 
 $fields{"Name"} = "Name";  
 $fields{"email"} = "Email"; 
 $fields{"Phone"} = "Phone"; 
 $fields{"Address"} = "Street Address";
 $fields{"City"} = "City";  
 $fields{"State"} = "State"; 
 $fields{"Zip"} = "Zip Code"; 
 $fields{"Classification"} = "Classification"; 
 $fields{"Ad-Headline"} = "Headline"; 
 $fields{"Ad-Content"} = "Ad Content"; 
 $fields{"Words"} = "Word Count"; 
 $fields{"Weeks"} = "Weeks to Run"; 
 $fields{"WordCount"} = "Total Words"; 
 $fields{"Rate"} = "Word Rate"; 
 $fields{"GrossAmountDue"} = "Gross Amount"; 
 $fields{"NonProfit"} = "Non Profit Ad?"; 

$item_name   = $_POST['item_name'];
$amount   = $_POST['amount'];
$currency_code  = $_POST['currency_code'];
$no_shipping = $_POST['item_number'];
$shipping = $_POST['item_number'];
$cmd   = $_POST['cmd'];
$bn  = $_POST['bn'];
$no_note = $_POST['item_number'];
$lc   = $_POST['lc'];
$business   = $_POST['business'];

 $body = "This Ad has been submitted:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){   $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]); } 

 if($from == '') {print "You have not entered an email, please go back and try again";} 
 else { 
 if($name == '') {print "You have not entered a name, please go back and try again";} 
 else { 
 $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); 
 if($send) 
 {header( "Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" );} 
 else 
 {print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please contact us at info.whatzup@gmail.com"; } 
 }
}



 ?>
```

Comment: It would help if you posted a code sample of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I did in another question but I had a ton of views and no helpi tried with less info this time (lol). I added a link to my source as i don't see an easy way to use just part of it.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals Do you have any ideas? Is there any part of my code I should be showing? I'm honesty completely stumped...

Comment: It would help if you post the function (event handler) that is invoked to submit the form.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals I wrote a php script to handle emailing to myself... I'm thinking I can just submit my post values to paypal from here and redirect? Am I at least on the right track?

Comment: Does this help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243746/paypal-and-php

Comment: @Aaron that helps and I saw it earlier today, basically all I need to know now is how to fill my hidden input fields once I redirect to contact.php. what do I put in the "value" section that will populate it with the value of the same input that was submitted with the form on the previous page? Basically I have an <input> field that's hidden and it getswritten to by a JavaScript function, then on submit I need to grab that value and put it in my hidden input field before having the form submitted and redirected to PayPal. Make sense? Lol

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949847/hidden-field-in-php

Comment: @Aaron that looks promising! I'm not at work till tomorrow afternoon when I can try it out... Thanks. This question started out as one thing and then I realized better ways of doing it... So I do apologize to everyone because it isn't exactly the same question anymore, but the point here is to get help whether you find the answer to a question or a solution to a problem it is still helpful. So go ahead and vote it down if people want to, I don't think I did anything wrong or misused the site.